# mysql procedures - running total

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cumulative-sum

When trying to run this in the SQL window in phpmyadmin the following error is returned..

## SQL

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `stock_in_stock_ids` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `stock_in_stock_ids`(_running_total_limit INT, _product_id INT, _block_id INT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _running_qty INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _id INT;
    DECLARE _qty INT;
    DECLARE _ids TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE _cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id, qty
        FROM stock
        WHERE block_id=_block_id && type=2 && product_id=_product_id
        ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN _cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH _cur INTO _id, _qty;

        IF done THEN
            SET _ids = '';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET _running_qty = _running_qty + _qty;
        SET _ids = CONCAT_WS(',', _ids, _id);

        IF _running_qty >= _running_total_limit THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE _cur;

    RETURN _ids;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

## error

```
#1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

## update (working solution)

```
SELECT qty, price_cost, @running_total:=@total running_total, @total:=@total+qty total
FROM stock, (SELECT @running_total:=0, @total:=0) vars
WHERE block_id=101 && type=2 && product_id=20
HAVING running_total<=3000
ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a stored procedure but are using a function. There's a difference, you know?

Also I think you don't need a procedure at all, let alone a cursor. Cursors are expensive as hell.

Does this get you what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
  id, 
  qty,
  @running_total:=@running_total + qty as running_total
  FROM stock
  , (SELECT @running_total:=0) vars
  WHERE block_id=_block_id && type=2 && product_id=_product_id
  ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC
) sq 
WHERE running_total <= $yourRunningTotalLimit
```

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read more about these internal vars `@running_total:` ?? What is it called?

Comment: It looks like it returns what I want! :D

Comment: Those are user-defined variables. You can read more about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html What I did with the `, (SELECT @running_total:=0) vars` is just initializing them on the fly in a query. It's the same as `SET @running_total := 0; SELECT ...` without the `, (SELECT @running_total:=0) vars` part.

Comment: but what if the table has 10000 rows and only after the first 5 rows the limit is reached? will the query then run through all 10000 rows before it returns the result?

Comment: Could be. But with appropriate indexing 10000 rows is nothing. In my job I'm dealing with millions of rows and such a query shouldn't take longer than a second.

Comment: I have a problem.. The last row isn't fetched.. The first row which exceeds the limit needs to be a part of the result too.. I need to do some kind of a do-while loop in the query.. Have updated the question with the new query

Comment: Hi again.. Found a solution without the sub-query.. Question updated :)